# Powershell sites export

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to use Powershell and the webadministration module to output a list of sites and bindings.  I am having a lot of trouble getting the data into a format that I can use.  When I run Get-Website I get...

```
Site   SiteNumber   Status   Path   Binding1
                                    Binding2
                                    Binding3
```

How can I massage the data so that I get something like...

```
Site   SiteNumber   Status   Path   Binding1
Site   SiteNumber   Status   Path   Binding2
Site   SiteNumber   Status   Path   Binding3
```

I have run into this issue multiple times and I would be very happy to find a way that I don't have to edit the data manually in Excel.

Thanks in advance!

~K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
Get-Website | % {`
$name = $_.Name;
$_.Bindings | `
 Select-Object -ExpandProperty Collection |`
 Select @{n='Name';e={$name}}, @{n='Binding';e={$_.protocol + ' ' + $_.bindingInformation}}
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked.  Now I just need to sort out why so I can do it again!